# CSS3 media query doesn't work

Tags: css, screen, media, device

I have the following code:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='only screen and (min-device-width : 1281px)' href='css/screenAllLarge.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='only screen and (min-device-width : 800px) and (max-device-width : 1280px)' href='css/screenSmaller.css' />
```

it is supposed to work for screen resolution 1281px and above. But When I re-size the screen it still applies the same **screenAllLarge.css** CSS file
I also changed the `media='only screen'` to `media='screen` but no luck. I am testing this with Firefox.

What am I doing wrong?
thank you

Comment: and where is the code?

Comment: Can you show your code in your post?

Comment: @Mooseman he did but it wasn't formatted properly. We can edit such posts ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

You must have cover the two differents options, set the intervals correctly

```
media='only screen and (min-width: 1281px)' href='css/screenAllLarge.css' 
media='only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1280px)' href='css/screenAllSmall.css'
```